# Sql Server Dynamic Database Partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, partitioning

Is there anything called dynamic partitioning in SQL server? If so how can i implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have an automatic sliding window table partition that will keep say the last X days data in one partition and move everything else

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122(SQL.90).aspx